# How to change the column order of an Azure database table in Visual Studio

Tags: sql, database, azure, visual-studio, azure-sql-database

I've been searching all afternoon for the way to re-order columns of an Azure database table in MS Visual Studio 2022. No luck.

In other applications columns are easily re-arranged by dragging or cut & paste.

No can do here. At this point, I'm not even sure columns can be moved in VS.

I'm only interested in the VS output view. I'm not interested in altering the database.

More specifically, I need two columns, which are on opposite ends of the table to be moved next to each other for a QA task. If this can't be done, I would have to jump or scroll from one end of the row to the other (across multiple screen views). If I can compare the columns next to each other, the task will take hours. If I can't, it will take weeks.

I guess another option would be to temporarily hide all the columns in between. That would be a less preferable but acceptable solution, as well.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Using query `SELECT col1, colN, * FROM table` and/or creating view on the database?

Comment: Are there no tools or functions in VS that can handle the task? Has to be coded? @LukaszSzozda

Comment: Could you share a screenshot on a specific output you want to reaarange?

Comment: The order of the column in the table doesn't matter. If you want the columns in a specific order when you `SELECT` from the table, then define that order in your `SELECT`. You cannot change the ordinal position of a column in a table; you would have to create a *new* table.

Comment: @Larnu, "You cannot change the ordinal position of a column in a table; you would have to create a new table." This is the answer. Please post as an answer, with supporting details, so I can accept.

Answer (score 2):

If the table has no data in it then just replace it with one that has columns in the order you want.

If the table contains data then

1. Create a new table with the columns in the order you want
2. Copy the data from the old to new table
3. Drop the old table, rename the new table

Or create a view over the existing table and query the view rather than the table

Comment: As they say in the Mandalorian: "This is the way".

Comment: Creating a view over the existing table seems like the best option to me. That way you don't have to worry about any data syncing between the original table and then new table?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I'm aware of these options (plus others, like outputting the data into a web page with editable HTML fields). I was hoping there was a way to simply re-arrange the columns in a table with data. Again, thanks.

Comment: You could always just write a stored procedure or user defined function that takes as parameters the table name, and then the columns in the correct order.  Then you could just call the stored procedure or function from within Visual Studio.